# Hotkey for automator service without giving permissions to all applications

Tags: security, automator

I have created an automator workflow; then I have created a keyboard shortcut in the Keyboard Settings to run this as a Quick Action on a keypress.

All of this works. But the workflow seems to run in the security context of the application which was active when I pressed the hotkey.

The activity inside the service has nothing to do with the current application (it takes a screenshot and then does something with it); it doesn't access the "current" application in any way.

It needs to access the System Events, and thus security kicks in. I then have to enable access to those features for any application which happened to be in the foreground when I hit the hotkey.

Is it possible to avoid this - i.e. run my service in a context of its own?

EDIT for clarification: The workflow clicks menus of applications, and sends keystrokes.

```
... take a screenshot ...
... startup GIMP ...

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "GIMP-2.10"

...
        click menu item "From Clipboard" of menu 1 of menu item "Create" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1

...
        keystroke " "
...
```

As an example, say I press the hotkey while Emacs is in front. I then get a security prompt asking me to allow some security aspects for *Emacs*. I neither want do give Emacs any permissions, nor do I want to repeat this for any other application which might be in focus when I take a screenshot later.

Comment: A service exports features for other applications to use - that is what it does.  System Events should have its own permission - how are you using it?

Comment: @red_menace: I am using it like here https://www.guidingtech.com/25775/custom-shortcut-apps-mac-automator/ (Automator => create service; keyboard settings => create shortcut in the "Services" section). The term "service" is a bit misleading here as far as I can tell (nothing is actually running in the background, like a daemon in Unix language), but that's what the english Catalina calls it...

Comment: I am aware of what it is, whatever it is called (these days it is "Quick Action").  There is a system application that deals with activating and running the workflow - the service is is made available in the contextual menu based on what it has been specified to receive.  My question was about what is _in_ the workflow, as System Events doesn't have a command for screenshots, and would have its own permissions.

Comment: @red_menace, that sounds right ("Schnellaktion" in German). I have edited the question to remove the word "service", and given a code extract.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue. What worked for me:

1: Saving the automator workflow as an application (File > Convert To > Application. Save > File Format = Application).

2: Then creating a separate Automator Quick Action with the sole purpose of launching the application created in 1 (File > New > Quick Action. Save normally as a workflow.).

The application containing the target workflow (1) will then need to be given Accessibility permissions via the usual (Security and Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility) and the key shortcut should be bound to the workflow (2) as you described.

This successfully bypasses the security settings of the currently active application by running the workflow in a self-contained app (with its own Accessibility preferences) negating the need for multiple permissions.

Comment: Nice idea worked pretty well